# how to order-by descending order file name with manageQuery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-file

I am building an android gallery and i would like to display the images in descending order by file name

but i am unsure what to put in the last field of my managedQuery:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[] {"%LC/images%"},  
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "dsc");// order here ?? help
```

Comment: please check this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705332/show-latest-on-top-in-a-list

Answer (score 3):

```
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED;              
cursor = managedQuery(
               MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
               columns, null,
               null, orderBy + " DESC LIMIT 5");
```

"DESC" - descending order
"Limit 5" - first five records, if you want all then discard from the query.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure because I'm not sure about what sort of database you're using.

But it looks like you want this line:

MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "dsc"

to tell the query to sort by _ID in descending order.

The first problem is simple. You need a space between  "_ID" and "dsc".  It's currently being joined right together and I don't think "_IDdsc" is really what you wanted. So change it to

MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " dsc"

Since you want to sort by filename, you'd just need to use that column name instead of _ID...unless _ID is the file name.

And i'll also mention...I think most databases use "desc" instead of "dsc"...but that's just what I've seen and maybe not the case here.  Or just take it off if you really don't want a reverse sort.

Comment: Thank you.. just so you know this not a database but instead a folder of images onthe sdcard of an android device. My app has a custom camera that saves pictures to a folder on the sdcard with file names that are generated by a time stamp so ordering them by name in desending order should put the last photo taken first

Comment: I wanted to double check and confirmed it should be " DESC" to sort descending.