# How to sort files using datetimestamp

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-sdcard

I am **capturing images**, then **storing into SD Card** and **showing in a List**, but here i need a small change, ***still i am getting old on top and latest at bottom***, so now ***i want to show latest picture on the top*** on the basis of datetimestamp using as a part of file name.

**UploadActivity.java** code:-

```
 String fileName;

 static List <String> ImageList;

  /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
    ImageList = getSD();

    // ListView and imageAdapter
    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 
    }

    public static List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
        String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/SamCam/";
        f = new File (string+ CameraLauncherActivity.folder+ "/");
        files = f.listFiles ();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                file = files[i];
                Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
                it.add (file.getPath());
            }
    return it;  
    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;

            public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            context = c;

        }
```

**Note:** I am using date/timestamp while storing my images into SD Card.

so finally it looks like this:

```
  AU_20140328163947_1_4_X-1-4-006.jpg
```

and **still files listing** in below format, like below:

```
AU_20140328163947_1_4_X-1-4-006.jpg

 AU_20140328163948_1_4_X-1-4-007.jpg

 AU_20140328163949_1_4_X-1-4-008.jpg
```

but i **want to list files** in below format:-

```
AU_20140328163949_1_4_X-1-4-008.jpg

 AU_20140328163948_1_4_X-1-4-007.jpg

 AU_20140328163947_1_4_X-1-4-006.jpg
```

**Code to Delete Image in a List:--**

```
// btnDelete
        final ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Image");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this image?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                // to get fileName
                                fileName = ImageList.get(position).toString().substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());
                                // to get SD card path (Folders+fileName)
                                 String fileToDelete = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Pictures/SamCam/" + CameraLauncherActivity.folder+ "/" + fileName;
                                 Log.d("FileToDelete", fileToDelete);
                                  File myFile = new File(fileToDelete);
                                  // if image exists
                                      if(myFile.exists())
                                          // delete image
                                        myFile.delete();
                                      // get position and delete
                                      ImageList.remove(position);
                                      // to refresh the view
                                 ((BaseAdapter) lstView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                                 dialog.cancel();
                            }
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return convertView;

            }   
        }
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480724/how-to-get-the-date-taken-and-display-it

Comment: u need to use file properties like lastmodified date and time to show images

Comment: try sorting it on the basis of the name of file using collections.sort method

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille can you show me the way ?

Comment: @Moon try the answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you getting data in reverse order than you can use reverse loop.

Try below loop

```
for (int i = files.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
file = files[i];
Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
it.add (file.getPath());
}
```

instead of

```
 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
      file = files[i];
      Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
      it.add (file.getPath());
  }
```

**or sort data with particular field**

Sort array data before using in for loop and use same loop..

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<Object>()
{
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return +1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

});

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
      file = files[i];
      Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
      it.add (file.getPath());
  }
```

Comment: still a small issue, like i have 5 images in a list, and i deleted 3 number image, and capture another image, now back to list and getting 6 captured image in place of 3.. why? whereas 6th image has to be show on top, i also posted code which i am using to delete image in a list

Comment: brother whenever you come, please try to resolve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777896/how-to-reference-holders-view-in-separate-method

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaStore ContentProvider for this job
Save the image using MediaStore using this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

And you can query the image using this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#query%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)

Set the order by as MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Collections.sort` method in your list adapter to sort the values according to the image file name like:

```
Collections.sort(ImageList, new Comparator<String>() {
  int compare(String obj1, String obj2) {
        return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
  }
});
```

`compareTo` method and also `compareToIgnoreCase` method, use wichever you think is appropriate, and also, you can experiment with obj1 and obj2, that is, you could swap the condition to:

```
 return obj2.compareTo(obj1);
```

That way your list will be sorted. Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

Since you know that the format is _ and then -.jpg, what you can do is in the comparator split the value from - like:

```
Collections.sort(ImageList, new Comparator<String>() {
  int compare(String obj1, String obj2) {
        String[] obj1Arr = obj1.split(-);
        String[] obj2Arr = obj2.split(-);

        obj1Arr = obj1Arr[1].split("."); // to just get the counter value
        obj2Arr = obj2Arr[1].split(".");

        return obj1Arr[0].compareTo(obj2Arr[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: bro not getting this: String obj1, String obj2 and you can see more code,may be helpful to teach me, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553802/custom-listview-scroll-hiding-progressbar-process-and-imageview

Comment: in the adapter class inside the constructor write this code in order to sort it, but then m not sure about the progress bar hiding and all.

Comment: so should i need to place your given code as it is in the constructor of adapter class, am i right ? to sort records

Comment: tried getting same result old file name on top and latest at bottom! why ? any way to get rid of by this

Comment: i am also using counter while naming my images, like: "-" + getNextNumber() + // counter ...... so can we use this counter to show latest file on top ?

Comment: bro same thing i asked earlier

Comment: i am saving image as "AU_" + // prefix
                timeStamp + "_" + // datetimestamp
                LoginActivity.strEID + "_" + // eID
                LoginActivity.strOID + // oID 
                        "-" + getNextNumber() + // counter 
                        ".jpg"   for more check above

Comment: check the edit and try it, if it doesnt work as is, change the positions of obj1Arr and obj2Arr in the comparisons

Comment: thanks for your support, but still not resolved, and i posted my updated code you can check now

Comment: thats what i am saying @Moon change the comparator to the new comparator iv written below the edit. and try that

Comment: check my edit please, m sorry for the mistake. change `obj1Arr[0].split` to `objArr[1].split`