# how to show at top last saved photo?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

**how to show at first (top) of last saved photo ?**

> i want to show last saved photo as first in custom gallery

**i am using universal image loader library**

**java file**

> i able to get all images but cant able to get last image as first

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming.Md5FileNameGenerator;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.QueueProcessingType;
import com.pmb.lovephotoframe.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomGallery extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
    File[] listFile;
    String applicationname = "Love Photo Frame";
    ImageView backmain, backhome;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_gallery);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Greeting Cards");
        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar1 = getSupportActionBar();
        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_gallry_actionbar);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ed145b")));
        applicationname = "Love Photo Frame";
        // getFromSdcard();

        initImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(Color.GREEN).showImageOnFail(Color.BLACK)
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, getfromcard());
        imagegrid.setAdapter(adapter);
        DisplayImage.grid = imagegrid;
        imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayImage.class);
                CustomAdapter c = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getfromcard());
                i.putExtra("imageID", c.getItem(position));
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });

        backmain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_main);
        backhome = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_home);
        backmain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent b1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                b1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(b1);
            }
        });

        backhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent b1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                b1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(b1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent b1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        b1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(b1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }

         public ArrayList<String> getfromcard() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Method Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File file = new File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            applicationname);

    File[] sortedByDate = file.listFiles();

    if (sortedByDate != null && sortedByDate.length > 1) {
        Arrays.sort(sortedByDate, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                return (int) ((object1.lastModified() > object2.lastModified()) ? object1.lastModified() : object2.lastModified());
            }
        });
        sortedByDate = file.listFiles();


        for (int i = 0; i < sortedByDate.length; i++) {

            f1.add(sortedByDate[i].getAbsolutePath());

        }


    }

    return f1;
}
/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}*/
}
```

Comment: Would reversing the ArrayList with `Collections.reverse(f);` be a suitable solution? Or you just want to remove the last element and place it in the front?

Comment: @TheSunshinator removing ?? didn't get that .. i juts want to display at first the last saved photo to the my custom gallery....

Comment: @TheSunshinator i tried file.lastModified();  but no luck

Comment: solved [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705332/how-to-sort-files-using-datetimestamp?answertab=active#tab-top]